# Run a bat hidden and as admin the same time

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, batch-file

I have a `bat` file that can run for more than an hour due to the things it does. Can I make it somehow run hidden and in admin mode?

I have found a way to make it run hidden with vbs:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\Ab\Desktop\vi\nove.bat" & Chr(34), 0

Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I would prefer to find a way to put them inside the batch file but I think it's not possible so a `vbs` file would be ok as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `runas` verb of the `Shell.Application` object's [ShellExecute method](http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html) will run with elevated permissions.  You can run it hidden by the same way you've done so in your current script, by setting the `window` handle to 0.

```
set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
' shell.ShellExecute "application", "arguments", "path", "verb", window
shell.ShellExecute "move.bat",,"C:\Users\Ab\Desktop\vi\", "runas", 0
set shell=nothing
```

Comment: Thank you mate it runs ok.Only one question as soon as i run it i get a popup windows saying user account control and it asks me to confirm the running(i guess its for running as admin) is there a way to bypass it?I mean to run without asking confirmation

Comment: Sure.  Turn off UAC.  It might not prompt for elevation if you launched the `cmd` console as administrator (right-click --> run as administrator).  I'm not sure.  I have UAC turned off on my machine, so I can't test that theory.

Comment: I was thinking somehow without the UAC but as i read i don't think its possible. thank you so much for your time mate and your help and i accepted your answer :)